# How to add a custom go code in helm charts?

Tags: rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm

i'm trying to mimic the Rabbitmq's password hash generation algorithm in my helm chart:
[How to generate password_hash for RabbitMQ Management HTTP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306350/how-to-generate-password-hash-for-rabbitmq-management-http-api)

I need to work with bytes, instead of strings, so obviously the following template did not work:

```
{{ printf "%s%s" "salt" ("saltpass" | sha256sum) | b64enc }}
```

Is there any way to add my custom go code?

Also, if not, is there any option to work with bytes there? (convert string to UTF-8 bytes, then use the sha256sum and the b64enc on bytes? or they have only string implementation?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This unfortunately isn't possible, since Helm can't expose the actual Go types, it's really just giving you yaml/text. Here are some references that might help explain this better:

- https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#template-functions-and-pipelines
- https://godoc.org/text/template
- http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/

Hope this helps.

Out of curiosity, why do you need to work with bytes in this case?

Comment: I think it's adding \0 to the sha256 compute, so it's not accurate. thus, i cannot replicate the RabbitMQ's hashing algorithm in helm charts

Comment: Yeah that could be tricky. My only suggestion would be to try using `helm template --debug` with some intermediate steps/variables to try and see the different stages/steps of the data and validate if this extra `\0` is there or not. For example `{{ "saltpass" | sha256sum }}`, then `{{ "saltpass" | sha256sum | b64enc }}`, then finally `{{ printf "%s%s" "salt" ("saltpass" | sha256sum) | b64enc }}` as just one approach.

Comment: Ill try, thank you. I do have a feeling it will be kinda tricky, i would hate to run an external tool to generate the hash and the support 2 values in the template, one for the regular password and one for the hashed

Comment: well, i've tested it - sadly helm's sha256 actually converts the bytes to their string hex values, Rabbit needs it as the raw bytes (in base64

Comment: @ArielB Apologies to revive old thread. I'm facing exactly the same issue. I want to provide randomly generated hash to rabbitmq helm chart value.. Did you find any solution (strictly using helm) without running external tool?