# RabbitMQ boot failed error : {'EXIT',{error,<<"{not_base64,<<\"guest\">>}">>}}}}

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to configure RabbitMQ using rabbitmq.config. I am getting error {could_not_start,rabbit,{error,<<"{not_base64,<<\"guest\">>}">>}}

I have created rabbitmq.conf and definitions.json

```
[
  {rabbit, [
    {loopback_users, []}
  ]},
  {rabbitmq_management, [
    {load_definitions, "/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json"}
  ]}
].
```

```
{
    "rabbit_version": "3.6.6",
    "users": [
     {
      "name": "guest",
      "password_hash": "abcd",
      "hashing_algorithm": "rabbit_password_hashing_sha256",
      "tags": ""
     },
     {
      "name": "admin",
      "password_hash": "abcd",
      "hashing_algorithm": "rabbit_password_hashing_sha256",
      "tags": "administrator"
     }
    ],
    "vhosts": [
     {
      "name": "\/abc"
     }
    ],
    "permissions": [
     {
      "user": "guest",
      "vhost": "\/abc",
      "configure": ".*",
      "write": ".*",
      "read": ".*"
     }
    ],
    "parameters": [],
    "policies": [],
    "queues": [],
    "exchanges": [],
    "bindings": []
   }
```

Docker-compose file

```
rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq
    container_name: rabbitmq
    hostname: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
      - ./path/rabbitmq.config:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config:ro
      - ./path/definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json:ro
```

Error log:

```
=CRASH REPORT==== 30-Sep-2019::18:50:35 ===
rabbitmq    |   crasher:
rabbitmq    |     initial call: application_master:init/4
rabbitmq    |     pid: <1.123.1>
rabbitmq    |     registered_name: []
rabbitmq    |     exception exit: {bad_return,
rabbitmq    |                         {{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},
rabbitmq    |                          {'EXIT',{error,<<"{not_base64,<<\"guest\">>}">>}}}}
rabbitmq    |       in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 134)
rabbitmq    |     ancestors: [<0.136.0>]
rabbitmq    |     messages: []
rabbitmq    |     links: [<1.124.1>,<1.128.1>,<1.31.1>]
rabbitmq    |     dictionary: []
rabbitmq    |     trap_exit: true
rabbitmq    |     status: running
rabbitmq    |     heap_size: 587
rabbitmq    |     stack_size: 21
rabbitmq    |     reductions: 97
rabbitmq    |   neighbours:
```

What mistake I am making? It looks like I am making some mistake while configuring. But I am not able to identify it.

Comment: RabbitMQ version 3.6.6 is unsupported, first of all. `not_base64` means that the value you have for `password_hash` is not encoded in base64 correctly.

Comment: the Value of password_hash is incorrect both for the guest account and for the admin account. It is very nicely explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306350/how-to-generate-password-hash-for-rabbitmq-management-http-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Value of password_hash is incorrect both for the guest account and for the admin account.

```
"password_hash": "abcd"
```

If you want to generate your own Hash then It is very nicely explained in this answer

[How to generate password_hash for RabbitMQ Management HTTP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306350/how-to-generate-password-hash-for-rabbitmq-management-http-api)