# RabbitMQ invalid credentials with valid information for web management interface

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

While trying to configure and create an admin user for rabbitmq with a JSON file. The users are created. But I am getting the following error while logging in with valid credentials from the web management console.

```
2022-07-22 08:15:56.342071+00:00 [warning] <0.847.0> HTTP access denied: user 'admin' - invalid credentials
```

My configurations and docker files are as follows.

`rabbitmq.config`

```
[
  {rabbit, [
    {loopback_users, [admin]}
  ]},
  {rabbitmq_management, [
    {load_definitions, "/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json"}
  ]}
].
```

`definitions.json`

```json
{
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "guest",
      "password_hash": "abcd",
      "hashing_algorithm": "rabbit_password_hashing_sha256",
      "tags": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "admin",
      "password_hash": "admin123",
      "hashing_algorithm": "rabbit_password_hashing_sha256",
      "tags": "administrator"
    }
  ],
  "vhosts": [
    {
      "name": "/"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    {
      "user": "admin",
      "vhost": "/",
      "configure": ".*",
      "write": ".*",
      "read": ".*"
    }
  ],
}
```

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.9-management

COPY conf/rabbitmq.config /etc/rabbitmq/
COPY conf/definitions.json /etc/rabbitmq/
RUN chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json

CMD ["rabbitmq-server"]
```

I also tried to log in with `rabbitmqctl`

```
>>rabbitmqctl authenticate_user admin admin123

Authenticating user "admin" ...
Error:
Error: failed to authenticate user "admin"
user 'admin' - invalid credentials
```

When the password is changed with `rabbitmqctl change_password admin admin123` everything seems to work fine.

The only warning in the log on rabbitmq startup is

```
2022-07-22 08:15:30.218099+00:00 [warning] <0.652.0> Message store "628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L/msg_store_persistent": rebuilding indices from scratch
```

Could someone please tell me the possible cause and solution? If I've missed out anything, over- or under-emphasized a specific point, please let me know in the comments. Thank you so much in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definitions file must contain the **HASH** of the password, not the password itself. Generally what I do is set a user's password via `change_password` like you have, then export the current definitions. You'll notice that they contain the hashed password.

You can also generate the hash yourself. See this:

[How to generate password_hash for RabbitMQ Management HTTP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306350/how-to-generate-password-hash-for-rabbitmq-management-http-api)